# Regexp causes to hang infinitely

Tags: regex, groovy

I have following regexp, which never evaluates and hangs infinitely:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
String AUTOGENERATED_HEADER = "#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED HEADER =-=-=-"
String AUTOGENERATED_FOOTER = "#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED FOOTER =-=-=-"

String messages = '''#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED HEADER =-=-=-
a=b
c=d
x=y
#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED FOOTER =-=-=-
'''


Matcher matcher = messages =~ /${AUTOGENERATED_HEADER}[\r\n]+((.*[\r\n]*)*)${AUTOGENERATED_FOOTER}/
matcher.find()​
```

The problem is with part `(.*[\r\n]*)`. When I change it to `(.*[\r\n]+)`, it works.

You can experiment with regexp [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5099247972122624). Can anybody explain how is it possible ?

Comment: Too easy to diagnose: catastrophical backtracking. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK7tX5/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is a case of a catastrophical backtracking. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK7tX5/1). The culprit is the `(.*[\r\n]*)*` part that is enclosed with other subpatterns. The nested quantifiers cause too much backtracking that you can see on the *regex debugger* page at regex101.com.

A *solution* is to either use lazy dot matching: replace `[\r\n]+((.*[\r\n]*)*)` with `.*?` and add an `(?s)` modifier at the start of the pattern, or use an unrolled version (which is much better for long inputs, but requires some hardcoding).

See [`(?s)#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED HEADER =-=-=-.*?#-=-=-= AUTOGENERATED FOOTER =-=-=-`](https://regex101.com/r/tK7tX5/2) in action. Use

```
Matcher matcher = messages =~ /(?s)${AUTOGENERATED_HEADER}.*?${AUTOGENERATED_FOOTER}/
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the (?s) option, where dot matches also newline character. As a result, my regex turned out to be very simple `(?s)${AUTOGENERATED_HEADER}[\r\n]+(.*)${AUTOGENERATED_FOOTER}`

Comment: Note that `(.*)` contains a greedy quantifier and the regex you provided above will match from the first `${AUTOGENERATED_HEADER}` up to the *last* `${AUTOGENERATED_FOOTER}`.